# Run the system configuration once the system has been installed

Tags: 10.10, installation

the problem is the following.
I have an old computer that mounts a SATA Dvd Burner. The old MoBo (an AsRock P4VT8+) is not able to recognize the freaking burner when booting.
So I had to convert my IDE HD to USB HD and mount it on my laptop and install Ubuntu from there. The problem now is that I'm obviously getting kernel panic every now and then so I was wondering if it is possibile to rerun only the system and the hardware configuration.

**UPDATE**: I'm getting kernel panics once I moved the IDE HD back.

Comment: I was unable to clearly understand your description, you did the install into the HD using an USB enclosure in a laptop, and now you are planning to move the HD to an IDE conector on the PC, is that the case ?

Comment: exactly. That's the problem. I've already moved everything but I'm getting kernel panic all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing IDE / USB changes HDD name

as IDE your HDD name is /dev/hdXY
as USB is /dev/sdXY

you need to boot from a live CD and chroot to your disk, change sd with hd in /etc/fstab

you need to update grub configuration

```
update-grub
```

Comment: That actually solve almost every problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The system would have been setup with drivers etc specific to the laptop, and not that desktop, which is why it is likely to be having trouble. Redoing the configure steps as you suggested is no trivial matter - a world of much manual reading and web searching, as well as probably a chroot operation from a live CD, IF you can use the live CD on the target machine.

If the target machine refuses to recognize the burner, perhaps you could make a bootable USB stick from an Ubuntu LiveCD.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

This means you wouldn't need to depend on the burner and should be able to install on the target machine without moving the drive.

Comment: yeah but I can't use an usb, we're talking about an old file server.

Comment: Are you sure? according to the spec for the board, it has "ASROCK I/O Plus - supports up to 8 USB2.0 ports". http://www.asrock.com/MB/overview.asp?Model=P4VT8%2B . They would be rear ports though.